# Swift Content Tabs?

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app and I am required to have 3 tabs if you click on the first tab, its a tableview, second tab a different tableview, third tab, TextView, here is an image of what I am trying to do:

[image]

Every time I google looking for examples of something like this, I get referred to UITabBarController, I don't think a tab bar is what I am looking for.

Comment: The image looks like a Segmented Control (UISegmentedControl). You'd have to implement the view switching aspect manually.

Comment: The easiest way to achieve the behavior you described is by using a UITabBarController. It just won't look like your mockup out of the box.

Comment: You could use a view controller with your "tab buttons"at the top and a container view. You could then place the appropriate view controller in the container view as each tab button was selected. This is essentially what tab bar controller does,  it if you don't want the standard look and feel you will need to "roll your own".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Segmented Control (`UISegmentedControl`). 
You can see it in Action natively e.g. in both the Apple iTunes and Health App.

Instead of performing segues to different views with the `UITabBarController`, you can, using Interface Builder, connect it to your `UIViewController` like so

```
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
```

and in

```
viewDidLoad() {
    switch segmentedControl.selectedIndex {
         case 0: // Do something on your first picture
               someFunction()
         case 1: // Do something on your second picture
               performSegue(withIdentifier: "your identifier here", sender: nil)
         case 2: // Do something on your third picture
               image.isHidden = true
               button.isEnabled = false
         default: break
}
```

... etc. You could also initiate different View Controllers instead of manipulating just one View, which you can then access via segues.

Please see official Swift doc @ https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol?changes=_3

Answer (score 0):

I would create this layout programmatically. You want a custom look to it so I do not think the standard controls are your best option.

Here is a playground to get you started on one way this could be achieved:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 768, height: 924))
    let view2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 768, height: 924))
    let view3 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 768, height: 924))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 768, height: 1024)
        self.view.backgroundColor = .black

        // View to have a border around the buttons
        let box = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 300, height: 50))
        box.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        box.layer.borderWidth = 2
        self.view.addSubview(box)

        // Tab buttons
        let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 100, height: 50))
        button1.setTitle("Orange", for: .normal)
        button1.tag = 1
        button1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tabTouched(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button1)

        let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 140, y: 20, width: 100, height: 50))
        button2.setTitle("Blue", for: .normal)
        button2.tag = 2
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tabTouched(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button2)

        let button3 = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 240, y: 20, width: 100, height: 50))
        button3.setTitle("Green", for: .normal)
        button3.tag = 3
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(tabTouched(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        self.view.addSubview(button3)

        // Tab Views
        view1.backgroundColor = .orange
        self.view.addSubview(view1)

        view2.backgroundColor = .blue
        view2.alpha = 0
        self.view.addSubview(view2)

        view3.backgroundColor = .green
        view3.alpha = 0
        self.view.addSubview(view3)
    }


    // When each of the buttons are tapped we will hide or show the correct tab's view
    @objc func tabTouched(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view1.alpha = 1
                self.view2.alpha = 0
                self.view3.alpha = 0
            }
        } else if sender.tag == 2 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view1.alpha = 0
                self.view2.alpha = 1
                self.view3.alpha = 0
            }
        } else if sender.tag == 3 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
                self.view1.alpha = 0
                self.view2.alpha = 0
                self.view3.alpha = 1
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = ViewController()
```

You can copy and paste this into an empty playground to see it in action. Essentially this is showing or hiding the appropriate views based on which button is selected. You can swap out the views for view controllers if you so desire.